# how to deal with possible special characters when iterating files with for command in windows *.cmd file?

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, special-characters

the code is:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%X in (`dir /a-d /s /b "!search_path!" 2^>^&1`) DO @(
  set file_path=%%X
  rem do other stuff
)
```

Delayed expansion is on because the source path might have special characters like backticks percentages exclamation and ^ escape sing. All these characters are allowed in windows paths and I don't know if and where they will be present.
The problem arise what to do with double percent parameter %%X, how to pass it to another variable without expansion. If DE is on the exclamation sings will be treated as variables with and that would result with a range of weird errors. The same thing is if I disable DE - the same situation, but this time with percentages.

Any idea how to make these lines safe for every possible allowed path that can be found in windows system with no matter how weird characters ?

The problem boils to how to safe pass data from double percent for parameter into normal `%variable%` so the data can safe passed through delayed expansion from that moment.

Comment: the solution below works, no?

Comment: Well I have another metod with grep where grep changes particular characters like `!` and `^` to `!x!` and `!e!`. And before I have set local variables, so the error works against itself.

Comment: "Windows" "CMD" (as you tagged your question) doesn't have a `grep` command, does it?  I'm pretty sure I provided a viable solution to your question.

Comment: Ok , you're right in case of using only wha'ts provided in CMD. And I made mistake above, it was not grep but sed, particulary ssed (supersed) mod for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to adapt `FOR /R` to your needs, which will solve some of your escape efforts.  You can check the format/match of the file listing in your loop vs. in the `dir`.

`FOR /R` will traverse your directory tree (which you're doing anyway) and return the files that match the pattern you give.

Quick example to list all files of type TXT in a directory and it's sub-directories goes like this:

UPDATED:

This prints the contents of two files in my directory that have exclamation points in them:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (ex*!*.txt) do (
   type %%~i
)
```

Note the absense of delayed variable expansion.  Add'l variable references are found at the bottom of the `for /?` listing.

Comment: It won't solve how to safe pass data from `for` parameter into normal `%variable%`. There is the real problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `set` command that's not working for you?

Comment: a normal set command, that is `set file_path=%%X` isn't working when path contains `!`, the same is with percentages if DE is off, and `call set` isn't working with for double-percent parameters, this parameter always is expanded and processed before putting it into command, doubling `%` or putting percent sign into variable like `%%%%X` doesn't work.

Comment: to your updated examle: ok, but what if path contains `%` character itself ? a folder might be named `%folder%` ... see the problem ?

Comment: @rsk82, no, I'm not seeing the problem on my machine.  `For /r` is designed to work like that.  I just created a file named `%folder%`, and it printed just fine.

Comment: You may need to wrap the file name in quotes in case of spaces in the path/file, or you could just use the `%%~si` to limit it to short file names.